# Tenant Context for Spring Scheduled task - Cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

We have a job that is run via the Spring Scheduler (**@Scheduled**). The task/callable here should execute in a particular **tenant context**. This is not called via an HTTP request so we cant get the tenant context directly from the URL.
In SCP Neo the job uses the TenantContext API like this-
*String result = tenantContext.execute(tenant.getTenantId(), new MeteringJobExecutor());*
where MeteringJobExecutor is the callable that needs to be executed for a particular tenant.

- What is the alternate for TenantContext API in CF?
- How do we execute
  such tasks?

We need an approach by which we can co-exist on both Neo and CF with minimal design change.

Comment: Where do you get the `tenant` in your code snippet from? If you have no calling request you, to my understanding, have to direct tenant to work with.

Comment: We have the tenant ids stored in the db. We pick up the tenant id from there and try to execute in that tenant's context.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use SAP Cloud SDK for this. As Cloud SDK provide support for both Neo and CF. With SDK you can achieve the above as follows:

For tenant on CF:

```
TenantAccessor.executeWithTenant( new ScpCfTenant( "tenantname", "tenant.domain"),() -> {
    TenantAccessor.getCurrentTenant().getTenantId();
});
```

For tenant on Neo:

```
TenantAccessor.executeWithTenant( new ScpNeoTenant(tenantContext), () -> {
    TenantAccessor.getCurrentTenant().getTenantId();
});
```

Where the lambda expression is the callable method on the tenant.

I hope this works for you.

Greetings,
Tanvi

Comment: I added the dependency for sdk-bom as specified in many blogs for SAP Cloud SDK. However, i was unable to resolve the errors. Could you please guide on this?